# How to translate this part of Te lucis?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

I am trying to translate part of the [*Te lucis ante terminum (Revised Latin text)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Te_lucis_ante_terminum) I have trouble translating this:

> Præsta, Pater piíssime,
>
> Patríque compar Unice,
>
> cum Spíritu Paráclito
>
> regnans per omne sǽculum.
>
> Amen.

**Can somebody explain how to translate this?** Thanks.

My attempt.

1. Præsta; present singular imperative active of [praesto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praesto): **supply**!
2. Pater; Nomnitive singular of [pater](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pater#Latin): **The Father**
3. piíssime; Vocative singular of [piissimus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piissimus): **O the very pious one**
4. Patríque; Dative singular of [pater](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pater#Latin): **and to/for Father**
5. compar; ?
6. Unice; Vocative singular of [unicus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unicus): **O The only One**

The rest is: **With the Holy Spirit the comforter, who reigns through all ages. Amen.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about these two lines in particular?

> Præsta, Pater piíssime,
> Patríque compar Unice,

The words here are in a somewhat unusual order, to fit the meter and the rhyme. A more usual ordering would be something like:

> Pater piisime, Unice-que compar Patri, præsta…

I would translate this as "o most pious Father, and o One like unto the Father, vouch for…"

Grammatically, note that *pater* and *compar* are both also vocative—for most words, the nominative and the vocative look identical. So *Pater piisime* is a single vocative phrase ("o most blessed Father"), and *Unice compar* is also a single vocative phrase ("o One, like unto"). *Compar* acts like *par* "equal", and usually goes with a noun in the dative (the thing being compared to): in this case, the Father.